# Validation error is not coming up and page is not responding after clicking button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation, developer-console, developer

I'm trying to show some validation error on my aura component for lightning:select field before saving the field must have some value if not selected picklist value trying to show some validation but getting an error.

After clicking button no error coming and page is not responding.

Any suggestions how to place some validation for lightning:select picklist field ?

```
<lightning:select aura:id="Inputcasecommentcategory" value="{!v.caseComment.ET_Comment_Category__c}" onchange="{!c.onPicklistChange}" name="Comment Category" label="Comment Category" required="true">
    <option value="">--None--</option>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldMap}" var="i" indexVar="key">
        <option text="{!i.value}" value="{!i.key}" selected="{!i.key==v.caseComment.ET_Comment_Category__c}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
<lightning:button label="Save" iconPosition="left" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.doSave}" />
```

// controller code

```
doSave: function(component, event, helper) {
    var Inputcasecommentcategory = component.find("Inputcasecommentcategory");
    var valueCategory = Inputcasecommentcategory.get("v.value");                        
    if(valueCategory == null || valueCategory == '--none--' ||  valueCategory == ''){
        Inputcasecommentcategory.set("v.errors", [{message:"Case Category is Required."}]);
    } else {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Regards,
Basha